# Is a subset of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ locally compact Borel space?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, compactness, book-recommendation

I am trying to understand some algorithms and at some point I got stuck on the definition of locally compact Borel spaces. Is a subset $Y$ of $\mathbb{Z}^n$  ($Y \subset \mathbb{Z}^n$) locally compact Borel space?

I would appreciate any references that explain these concepts in a simple way (eg. lecture notes, books etc.). Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is your definition of  locally compact Borel space?

Comment: Do you mean just locally compact space?